# Variable as C++11 attribute argument

Tags: c++, c++11, eos

Given an attribute that accepts a string argument, like [`[[deprecated("reason")]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated), is it possible to use anything else other than a hardcoded string literal?

In my case, I'm developing a smart contract for the EOS.IO blockchain which exposes the [`[[eosio::on_notify("account::action")]]`](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.6.0/guides/generator-attributes.html#eosioonnotify) attribute and I would like to extract the `"account::action"` part in a configuration file.

I understand that there is an EOS.IO specific Stack Exchange network but I think this question applies to all C++11 attributes.

#### Attempts so far

I tried defining these parameters as static const strings in a namespace in a `config.hpp` header:

```
// ...omitting irrelevant parts

namespace config {
    static const std::string test = "eosio.token::transfer";
}
```

and later importing the header and using the static string:

```
// contract.cpp

// ...omitting irrelevant parts

#include "config.hpp"

class [[eosio::contract]] myapp : public contract {
public:

    [[eosio::on_notify(config::test)]]
    void on_transfer();
};
```

However, the compiler complains:

> error: 'on_notify' attribute requires a string [[eosio::on_notify(config::test)]]

Comment: Also this form of attribute was introduced in C++17, not C++11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Attributes are baked into your source code literally.

You could use the preprocessor though, with help from your build system to define the desired macro.